# How to structure Java code of a library project?

Tags: java, maven

I have some years experience in developing Java applications right now, but it is the first time I develop a (Java 8) [library](https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptofs/) which has to be used by external developers. Thus I do not wan't to expose anything (Classes, Methods, etc.) except the API.

Thus I started implementing it in a single package and kept everything in default scope which is only internal.

Because implementing this needs many many classes which will maybe split up into more classes to ensure maintainability and testability that package becomes way to large to my mind. In a regular project I would have created plenty of subpackages to structure the code but this isn't possible because this would lead to internal classes having public scope.

Do you have any ideas or know any ways (maybe involving the build system (maven) or other suggestions when using java 8) to make such code more structured without exposing more classes as needed? It's not that I couldn't live with a single package, it just doesn't feel right somehow.

Comment: There is no need to hide the implementation completely. Instead define a public API and document it, so people know to use that.

Comment: Well, you can play with `package-private` classes/methods to define what you want to be hidden to your user.

Comment: Some hints about your Maven POM. You should prevent using version ranges...

Comment: A whole book could be written in this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this would lead to internal classes having public scope.

Having developed such libraries for many years, this isn't as much of a problem as you might image as most developers will only use some of the documented classes and methods and don't go digging around in your code as they are aware the details might change and break their solution with an upgrade.

In short, if it's not documented, it doesn't exists for most developers.

Note: if developers wants to get into your code they can use reflection and making it private won't matter either. Or they can take a copy of the code and modify it and do whatever they like.

All you are doing is preventing developers how what to get into your code but not use reflection to do which is a small number.

> Do you have any ideas or know any ways (maybe involving the build system (maven) or other suggestions) to make such code more sturctured?

Java 9's Jigsaw have greater control. It allows you to determine what will be exported outside your JAR. This way you can have `public` members which can be used anywhere except from outside your JAR.

Answer (score 1):

First keeping everything into a single package is not a good idea cause separation of concerns is one key concept. Furthermore it's hard to find the public API in your current state of the code.

This means you have a package for the API which results into having a single module `whatever-api`(artifact name) and one for the implemtation `module-api-impl` etc. or some more (later).

This will also in resulting having separate packages and separates the code and tests etc. from each other and shows where you need to separate your code (may be you have coupled you core unintended.

Exposing things is done yes. The current Java do not allow such correct separation and clear definition of an API etc. (also from a technical perspective) This can be done starting with Java 9 you will really be able to separate internal from public things by using appropriate modules. The other possible way would be to using OSGi which has such separation and and a strict separation of public api and implementation.

Comment: A problem with OSGi is you have to be using an OSGi container to enforce the rules. Anyone who doesn't won't even know the restrictions are there.